# ServiceStack Session always null in MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 4 app using the service stack MVC powerpack, utilizing service stack's auth and session providers. I'm copying lot of logic from the social bootstrap API project. My controllers inherit from the following base controller:

```
public class ControllerBase : ServiceStackController<CustomUserSession>
```

which is implemented as:

```
public class ControllerBase : ServiceStackController<CustomUserSession> {}
```

`CustomUserSession` inherits from `AuthUserSession`:

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
```

After I log in, my `CustomUserSession` `OnAuthenticated()` method runs, but when I redirect back to my controller, the `UserSession` is not populated, e.g.

```
public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
{
    base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
    CustomFoo = "SOMETHING CUSTOM";

    // More stuff
}

public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // After having authenticated
        var isAuth = base.UserSession.IsAuthenticated; // This is always false
        var myCustomFoo = base.UserSession.CustomFoo; // This is always null

    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to issue within ServiceStack Google Group - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/servicestack/5JGjCudURFU

When authenticating with a JsonSeviceClient (or any serviceClient) from within MVC the cookies are not shared with MVC request/response.

When authenticating within a MVC Controller to ServiceStack, the MVC HttpContext should be sent to ServiceStack. Something like below should work...

```
var authService = AppHostBase.Resolve<AuthService>();
authService.RequestContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ToRequestContext();
var response = authService.Authenticate(new Auth
{
  UserName = model.UserName,
  Password = model.Password,
  RememberMe = model.RememberMe
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting IsAuthenticated to true and saving your session...

```
public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
{
    base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
    CustomFoo = "SOMETHING CUSTOM";
    session.IsAuthenticated = true;
    authService.SaveSession(session);

    // More stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but no luck. at this point the session is populated, i just can't read it using the ServiceStackController's UserSession property. i did find however that i do see the populated user session if i use the ICacheClient Cache property. so possibly an issue with the SessionAs extension method? gonna pull down the source to see what's going on there