# nullreference exception when adding session cookie to ServiceStack

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, servicestack

This question relies quite a bit on the question/answer here:

[Reconnecting to Servicestack session in an asp.net MVC4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160839/reconnecting-to-servicestack-session-in-an-asp-net-mvc4-application)

Basically, I have an asp.net MVC application that is using ServiceStack for authentication. As suggested in the question mentioned above I am adding a session cookie to the response and then adding it to the jsonserviceclient cookie container later.

Using this code to authenticate the user at the login screen:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult login(UserModel user)
    {
        try
        {
            var AuthResponse = client.Post(new Auth
            {
                provider = "credentials",
                UserName = user.user_id,
                Password = user.password,
                RememberMe = true
            });

            if (AuthResponse.SessionId != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(AuthResponse.UserName, true);
                var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ToResponse();
                response.Cookies.AddSessionCookie(
                    SessionFeature.PermanentSessionId, AuthResponse.SessionId); 

                return Redirect("/Default");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); 
            return Redirect("/");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

However, I am getting a null ref exception from the line:

```
response.Cookies.AddSessionCookie(SessionFeature.PermanentSessionId, AuthResponse.SessionId);
```

The stack trace looks like:

```
at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Cookies.ToHttpCookie(Cookie cookie)
at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Cookies.AddCookie(Cookie cookie)
at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Cookies.AddSessionCookie(String cookieName, String cookieValue, Nullable`1 secureOnly)
at FmStoreScreenMvc3.Controllers.AuthController.login(UserModel user) in <project> 51
```

I'm wondering if anything seems obviously wrong with this configuration.

**Update/note** 
I have changed the offending line (Where the nullref is thrown) to:

```
response.Cookies.AddSessionCookie("foo", "bar", false);
```

I still get the same error. Just hunting for what is null and why

Comment: Add a break point to that line, then work out what it is that is null.

Comment: Once you've figured that out you could update the question with the extra info. e.g. "Why is X null, I was expecting it to be Y"

Comment: @SeanH Can you retry with the latest version of ServiceStack?

Comment: @mythz Updated 3.9.64 -> 3.9.66, ended up with the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
response.Cookies.AddSessionCookie(
  SessionFeature.PermanentSessionId, AuthResponse.SessionId);
```

Try:

```
response.SetCookie(SessionFeature.PermanentSessionId, 
    AuthResponse.SessionId, TimeSpan.FromDays(14)));
```

Comment: "No overload for method 'SetCookie' takes 1 arguments" - Working on a workaround now

Comment: Seems to be working now that I modified the code a bit more. Will respond after a bit of testing. Thanks -S

Comment: @SeanH ok just noticed you're using a ServiceStack `IHttpResponse` instead of the underlying ASP.NET `HttpResponse`, updated answer.

Comment: thats exactly what I changed on my side :} Thank you